# How many days of supply did units in WW2 carry?

Tags: world-war-two

A typical infantry, and armoured battalion of the various sides....
(and if possible, at various stages of the war)

At what level were supplies (surplus to the immediate projected consumption) stockpiled? Brigade level? division level? army group level etc. ? Or was it centrally, through some sort of supply corps?

A breakdown on lines of this US classification perhaps. I am not looking for an exhaustive list of this table. Rough estimates would do. Food - ammo - fuel - spare parts.

I do not need a single exhaustive monolithic answer. It would help if you can give parts of the picture.

Was researching for making some mechanistic models in SQL. Perhaps even the backend of a game someday.

Also do any organised records of such exist? I tried looking but did not find it on the surface internet. Perhaps some books that I'll have to buy, which quote primary sources.

---

**Class I** Subsistence (food), gratuitous (free) health and comfort items

**Class II** Clothing, individual equipment, tent-age, organizational tool sets and kits, hand tools, unclassified maps, administrative and housekeeping supplies and equipment

**Class III** Petroleum, Oil and Lubricants (POL) (package and bulk): Petroleum, fuels, lubricants, hydraulic and insulating oils, preservatives, liquids and gases, bulk chemical products, coolants, deicer and antifreeze compounds, components, and additives of petroleum and chemical products, and coal.

**Class IV** Construction materials, including installed equipment and all fortification and barrier materials

**Class V** Ammunition of all types, bombs, explosives, mines, fuzes, detonators, pyrotechnics, missiles, rockets, propellants, and associated items

**Class VI** Personal demand items (such as health and hygiene products, soaps and toothpaste, writing material, snack food, beverages, cigarettes, batteries, alcohol, and cameras— nonmilitary sales items) and paperclips.

**Class VII** Major end items such as launchers, tanks, mobile machine shops, and vehicles

**Class VIII** Medical material (equipment and consumables) including repair parts peculiar to medical equipment. (Class VIIIa – Medical consumable supplies not including blood & blood products; Class VIIIb – Blood & blood components (whole blood, platelets, plasma, packed red cells, etc.)

**Class IX** Repair parts and components to include kits, assemblies, and sub-assemblies (repairable or non-repairable) required for maintenance support of all equipment.

**Class X** Material to support nonmilitary programs such as agriculture and economic development (not included in Classes I through IX).

**Miscellaneous** Water, salvage, and captured material.

Comment: This question as written would require volumes to even begin an adequate response. You are dealing with every level of unit, across 6 years and three continents and a wide variety of fortunes. If on the other hand you were interested in what a typical *dough boy* carried with him as supplies on June 6, 1944, that would be answerable.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I'd be interested in that too. The reason I left it so wide is because after looking for it, I doubt much data exists. So anything coming in would be good.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens instead of asking _how much did such and such unit carry?_ , and getting the answer, _we don't know_

Comment: D-Day is amongst both the most documented and most prepared for (by ***both*** sides) military events in the history of the world. If we don't have this information for that day, we surely won't have it for any other.

Comment: Good! Fixed it for youi.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens <cough> you took the life out of it

Comment: It's your question - and you seemed reluctant to make it answerable. My edit in no way is intended to be final - just to provide you with motivation to make it answerable. **I can't read your mind** and won't pretend to.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I'd rather, it was left as it were, and was put on hold if it came to that. Instead of the very benevolent motivations.

Comment: The edit history is available (click on the [editied xx  minutes ago](https://history.stackexchange.com/posts/48834/revisions) if you want to copy-paste material back in. BTW I have no intention to engage in an edit battle with you. As your post, you own it. Roll-back my edit if you so wish. But do so with eyes open. I will not retract my VTC until I see ***you*** make an edit I can live with.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question at reasonable length is impossible. However, the US Army Centre for Military History makes all their WWII histories available free of charge. Start [here](https://history.army.mil/html/bookshelves/collect/ww2-eto.html) with the two volumes on "Logistical Support of the Armies."